Static comparison function results in heap buffer overflow
class Solution {
private:
    static bool cmp(const int& a, const int& b)
    {
        return a >= b;
    }
public:
    long long function(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), cmp);
        return 0;
    }
};

Above code results in heap buffer over-flow if nums is:
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

but works fine if nums is:
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

I resolved this issue by making:
return a > b;

in cmp function instead of >=
But Can anyone tell me why >= is not correct?

the comparison function passed to sort is meant to return true if the first element should appear before the second element. For equal elements, you keep saying they should appear before each other.

Related: you don't need to write your own cmp, you can make it sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), std::greater<>{});
